# Conflicting Routes when referencing another module

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Consider the following code

```
angular.module('module1', []).
config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouteProvider", function($stateProvider){
    $urlRouteProvider.when('', 'Profile');
    $stateProvider.state('Profile', {
        url: '/Profile',
        templateUrl: '/path/to/template'
        controller: 'controller as ctrl'
    }
}]).
service('IWantToUseThisServiceInModule2', serviceFunction);

angular.module('module2', ["module1"]).
config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouteProvider", function($stateProvider){
    $urlRouteProvider.when('', 'Profile');
    $stateProvider.state('Profile', {
        url: '/Profile',
        templateUrl: '/path/to/template'
        controller: 'controller as ctrl'
    }
}]);
```

I'm trying to reference module1 in module2 to use a service in module1. However, I get the error that the state 'Profile' has already been defined. I can get around this error by changing the `profile` state in `Module2` to any other state. Now I don't get an error but when a route is not present, I still get routed to the `Profile` State. I understand that this is happening because the dependencies get initialized first. Is there a way around it? I want the routes in `Module2` to take preference.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just move your service to its own module?

Comment: what about a "route" module, with the configuration?

Comment: @Phil I thought of doing that but I only need some functionality from the service. My colleagues also didn't think refactoring the service was justifiable for this. I could've simply just copied the functions I needed and created a new service but I didn't want to repeat code as well. I was hoping last write for routes will win but that doesn't seem to be the case.